# Spring Boot Akka Dependency Injection

Tags: spring, scala, spring-boot, akka

was hoping to get some help with figuring out dependency injection things with Spring Boot and Akka using the Scala language.

Say I have an Actor `class ExampleActor extends Actor`

I was hoping to be able to `@Autowired` part of the actor such that I would be able to choose between two different dependencies to inject, if that makes sense I'm not totally sure lol?

Something like this

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class ExampleActor extends Actor {

    @Autowired
    // NEED HELP WITH DEPENDENCY INJECTION HERE!
    val dependency: DependencyInterface

    dependency.importantMethod

    def receive = {// stuff and things the actor takes care of}
}

// Unsure of what annotation to use
abstract class DependencyImplOne extends DependencyInterface {
    def importantMethod {// override dis method}
}

// Unsure of what annotation to use
abstract class DependencyImplTwo extends DependencyInterface {
    def importantMethod {// override dis method too}
}

// Unsure of what annotation to use
trait DependencyInterface { def importantMethod }
```

Very unsure about which annotations to use though, can anyone help me out lol???